# Incorrect encoding during PHP - MySQL interaction

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

In my mysql database, I use `utf8mb4_general_ci` encoding.

In the CMS config, the UTF-8 header encoding is set `('Content-Type: text / html; charset = utf-8');`

And also:

```
mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
```

But if I send a request through PHP (**If I use not Latin!**), then in the database I get the following:

[image]

And vice versa, what is displayed normally in the database, passing through PHP breaks as a result.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Something you should bear in mind - [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8mb4')
```

instead of your first line.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php